# How to respond to recruiters after a month of them contacting me?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, united-kingdom, email

Some recruiters contacted me just over a month ago either by message or phone call. I have not responded to them because of extenuating circumstances regarding my health and other's close to me. One of the recruiters gave me a take home assignment which I have not been able to complete due to the aforementioned reasons.

How do I respond to these recruiters to let them know that I've been dealing with issues regarding my health and others close to me, and that I am interested in the opportunities they contacted me about?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118784/discussion-on-question-by-myname-how-to-respond-to-recruiters-after-a-month-of-t).

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to delve into the details of your indisponibility. The simple fact that you answer to a month-old proposition shows that you are, in fact, interested. You could just say that health issues put you out of the market and made you unable to answer until now, and ask if the opportunities in question are still relevant as of today.

Concerning the take home assignment, regardless of the process in itself (because that's off-topic), mention it in your answer and wait for them to reply. There's a good chance it is no longer relevant, so you shouldn't work on it beforehand and possibly waste your time. They also might argue that it's been a month and that accepting your work would be unfair to other applicants, even if you were indeed unable to work during the last few weeks. They might give you another, so starting on the one they sent you would be, again, a waste of time.

Even if those opportunities are gone, they will probably remove you from the "not worth contacting" list, which will allow you to get the next ones.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good answer because it provides a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you. Don't forget to upvote the answer and/or to accept it if you found it satisfying enough.

Comment: Okay. When responding to them by message do I only mention one reason (i.e. my health issues), or mention the two reasons (the health issues of me and those close to me) in my question?

Comment: Health issues are more than enough to justify extended unavailability. You don't need to say more.

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking this. If recruiters contact you via LinkedIn or email it's totally ok to respond even months later. There is no need for you to give any excuses for that, in fact it's even better not to. If it's an external recruiter to the company they [will earn thousands of pounds placing you](https://www.topechelon.com/blog/how-do-recruiters-make-money-get-paid/#:%7E:text=They%27re%20more%20like%20commissioned,be%20talking%20about%20external%20recruiters.), they will definitely not be personally offended by your late reaction.

The case where you already agreed to make a home assignment will take a little bit of mending. However I think just saying you were busy/had other things on your mind will be enough, no need to go into much detail.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to guess what exactly the situation was between you and the recruiters.

If you've been ignoring their phone calls or email chasing until now, then one can imagine you may have created a minor feeling of inconsideration, and if you want that to be forgiven then the reason you give to them may have to be detailed, so that they can see the circumstances would obviously cause incapacity or overwhelming preoccupation.

You don't however have to tell them the specifics of the health condition "affecting you and others close to you", just as you haven't here, but that is only likely to invite speculation. They'll almost certainly let it drop and continue to deal with you, but it might lead to second-guessing at the margins - for example, it they feel they have an important client, and they worry you don't show up for an arranged interview due to unstated "health reasons" again, especially if they have a better candidate.

On the other hand, if you have only really been dealt with in a brief or impersonal way, and all balls were left in your court (and they haven't attempted to chase you up about anything outstanding, so that they haven't been ignored in consequence), then they are probably dealing with many candidates, many of whom will be expected to be flaky, and they will probably just treat it as one of those things and forget about it, regardless of how much detail you give.